# Unable to render more than 135 samples or gets hung

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Seems I'm only able to render 135 and no more, if try then get stuck on 2 sampling.

135 samples takes about about 4-6 minutes. I have memory, see image of OS info, Memory info. Thank you. [image: memory info ubuntu]

Comment: you should add more info like are you rendering on GPU? If yes, what happens on CPU? What do you mean by "get stuck on 2 sampling"?

Comment: By the way, judging by the text alignment of the number sliders in your screenshot, you are using a pretty outdated version of blender (<= 2.69). Consider [updating to a more recent version](http://askubuntu.com/q/169542/183331)

Comment: Thank you for responding, I just downloaded from SW ubuntu center, and have not changed any settings. I do not know what happens on CPU yet but will download a system monitor to check that.  Whta I meant by get stuck on 2 sampling  is that if try to sample 250 the  progress screen will always stop at 2/135.  No matter what number I put in for sample - even 10 sample is will be #/135. If set to 135 or less is will complete 135 rendering. If set above 135 program hangs at 2/135 until I press ESC.  I installed on a different computer, no difference in problem. Both PC's running Ubuntu.

Comment: updating to v2.78 didn't change problem

Comment: : Trinity [Radeon HD 7520G][AMD/ATI] Driver version 15.201.1151
     
                            Core (MHz)    Memory (MHz)
           Current Clocks :    685           667
             Current Peak :    685           667
  Configurable Peak Range : [334-685]     [667-667]
                 GPU load :    87%

Comment: Try lowering the size of the render tiles. Also do a test render using CPU, chances are that your GPU cannot deal with such task.

Comment: Is the problem is that I have a laptop? ( User Preferences > System > Compute Device, highlighted in blue says "None" and underneath that says CPU (no choice for GPU) - blender isn't compatible with OPEN CL rendering so its wortless to buy any amd GPU

Comment: Changed OpenSubdiv compute from 'none' to CPU and runs 9 seconds instead of 7 minutes. Wow! But still 135 sampling

Comment: oops my mistake, did run faster, had it on 10 samples insted. :(

Comment: I don't know what is different other than I'm doing peppers and the rendering looks fine. Perhaps the wine glasses surface material is what is screw. Consider this solved for now because it looks good in 135 samples. Thank you all.

Comment: Thanks  gandalf3, upgraded to 2.78a and able to render no problem @ 1000 samples. Noticed when doing an animation save it said "Path Tracing Tile #/135 - so upgrading fixed the problem . Thank You! Upgraded via command line